# Remove objects from this array of object when certain criteria is met

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, javascript-objects

I have this array of object in javascript.

```
var array = [ { DATA_ID: 1,
    DATA_NAME: 'XX',
    DATA_GROUP: 2313,
    CODE_NO: 1 },
  { DATA_ID: 6,
    DATA_NAME: 'YY',
    DATA_GROUP: 4213,
    CODE_NO: 2 },
  { DATA_ID: 4,
    DATA_NAME: 'ZZ',
    DATA_GROUP: 2123,
    CODE_NO: 3 },
  { DATA_ID: 8,
    DATA_NAME: 'ZZ',
    DATA_GROUP: 2123,
    CODE_NO: 3 } ]
```

I want to remove objects from the array of objects when the property CODE_NO === 3.

The result will look like this;

```
[ { DATA_ID: 1,
    DATA_NAME: 'XX',
    DATA_GROUP: 2313,
    CODE_NO: 1 },
  { DATA_ID: 6,
    DATA_NAME: 'YY',
    DATA_GROUP: 4213,
    CODE_NO: 2 }
]
```

I am using node.js v6

Comment: Show us some code, where you tried to do that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simple java script manipulation by [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) :

```js
var arr = [ { DATA_ID: 1,
    DATA_NAME: 'XX',
    DATA_GROUP: 2313,
    CODE_NO: 1 },
  { DATA_ID: 6,
    DATA_NAME: 'YY',
    DATA_GROUP: 4213,
    CODE_NO: 2 },
  { DATA_ID: 4,
    DATA_NAME: 'ZZ',
    DATA_GROUP: 2123,
    CODE_NO: 3 },
  { DATA_ID: 8,
    DATA_NAME: 'ZZ',
    DATA_GROUP: 2123,
    CODE_NO: 3 } ]

var res =arr.filter(function(elem){

  if (elem.CODE_NO != 3)
    return elem
})
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Elegant code! I was writing some long-winded code until I saw your answer. Brilliant! Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

**use this : **

```
    let array = 
     [ { DATA_ID: 1,
        DATA_NAME: 'XX',
        DATA_GROUP: 2313,
        CODE_NO: 1 },
      { DATA_ID: 6,
        DATA_NAME: 'YY',
        DATA_GROUP: 4213,
        CODE_NO: 2 },
      { DATA_ID: 4,
        DATA_NAME: 'ZZ',
        DATA_GROUP: 2123,
        CODE_NO: 3 },
      { DATA_ID: 8,
        DATA_NAME: 'ZZ',
        DATA_GROUP: 2123,
        CODE_NO: 3 } ];

        for (var key in array ){
          if(array[key].CODE_NO==3){
            delete array[key];
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll post an "alternative" solution if there's already Ramda project dependency. @asdf_enel_hak example is great purse JS so if you don't need extra deps, use that example.

Ramda based solution:

```
// complement is like logical not, if value is true returns false and on true returns false
// it does not return boolean value but new function
const codeIsNot3 = R.complement(
  R.propEq("CODE_NO", 3) // Property based equal check, without R.complement it would return all objects where code_no is 3
);
R.filter(codeIsNot3, arr);
```

Comment: Functional programming looks good. But I will need some time to understand the code. The code is short, yet not easy for people like me to understand.

Comment: That's true, added more comments about the functions used, also ramda docs is great place to go next.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work. The trick lies in using `array.splice(i,1)` to remove the object in question.

```
for (let i=0;i< array.length; i++  ){
      if (array[key].CODE_NO===3){            
        array.splice(i,1);
      }
   }
```

`array` is the array posted in your question.